# List to Map - Collectors.toMap()

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `List<String> abc` collection. I need to convert it into `Map<String, TreeSet<String>` where the key is the sorted string from `abc` and this string before sorting is added to the TreeSet.
It is possible using `Collectors.toMap()`?

ex. pseudocode:
`List<String> abc = ["ala","laa","qwe"]`

`Map<String, TreeSet<String> = {key = "aal" , values in treeset = "ala" , "laa"
key = "eqw" values in treeset = "qwe"}`

Comment: Can you provide example values on what list contains and what Map contains ?

Comment: whats the `TreeSet` value corresponding to `abc` keys should be?

Comment: Pseudocode added.

Comment: So you will have only one item in your Map for the whole list

Comment: I still don't get the rules for creating the set. Please explain it precise.

Comment: for each key set holds all the anagrams found in the list

Comment: Aha! You are talking about _anagrams_. And you think that this really important piece of information doesn't belong into the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`groupingBy` is the appropriate collector

```
Map<String, TreeSet<String>> map =    
    list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        s -> withSortedChars(s),
        Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if the keys also needs to be sorted, you can try below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> abc = Arrays.asList("ala", "laa", "qwe");
    Map<String, TreeSet<String>> sorted = abc.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Utils::sortByChar, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)));
    System.out.println(sorted);
}

public static class Utils {
    public static String sortByChar(String s) {
        char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        return new String(arr);
    }
}
```

output

```
{aal=[ala, laa], eqw=[qwe]}
```